# Problem with even spacing of links on horizontal navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, spacing

What I want to do is place the 'dave' link all the way to the left, Sarah all the way to the right, and have the rest of the link names evenly spaced between the two.  I got close to achieving that, but it doesn't look quite right.  Any help would be appreciated.

(navbar pic) [navbar pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2ZpR.png)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.topnav {
  background: rgb(207, 12, 12);
  background: radial-gradient( circle, rgb(223, 125, 125) 15%, rgba(245, 255, 1, 1) 59%, rgba(83, 236, 190, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 89%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}

a {
  margin: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!-- NavBar -->
<div class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="active" href="#home"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./the-family/dave.html" class="dave" id="hovercolor1">Dave</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./the-family/sara.html" class="sara" id="hovercolor2"
                >Sara</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./the-family/jeff.html" class="jeff" id="hovercolor3"
                >Jeff</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./the-family/melissa.html" class="melissa" id="hovercolor4"
                >Mel</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./the-family/lauren.html" class="lauren" id="hovercolor5"
                >Lauren</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./the-family/sarah.html" class="sarah" id="hovercolor6"
                >Sarah</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well

Comment: I edited the post to include the HTML as well.

Comment: Your first list item is empty but still takes up space. `<li><a class="active" href="#home"></a></li>`

Comment: Removing that did it! Thank you. I have no idea how, or why, that was there but....now it's gone.  I altered the 'a' element margins to 110px and it looks great.   This is only my second week of learning HTML and CSS. :p